# Correct way to apologise

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, forgiving-mechilah

As I've grown older, I've started to find the phrase "please forgive me" to be a little bit distasteful. It has a big fat "me" in it, and (especially when it is ritualised) it can easily convey the impression that one isn't genuinely regretful in the victim's suffering, just regretful that now one is "in trouble" for "having done something wrong" so they better get the victim to forgive them otherwise they will go to gehinom.

Of course, it doesn't have to mean this. [The way forgiveness generally works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2k3ooIfQy0&t=649s&ab_channel=RabbiManisFriedman) is when we see someone humble themself and apologise and seek to reconnect, it allows our compassion to overcome our sense of justice ("I am precious and he hurt me, he deserves to be punished"), and that opens the door to us considering that our oppressor is also someone precious, and shouldn't be held to a standard we don't hold ourselves to, and perhaps we might even have deserved it a little.. and then forgiveness can come.

So, "please forgive me" can mean "I miss your friendship, I miss you, and until you forgive me, I can't have that so please forgive me", which is a wonderful and beyond-reproachful thing to say (it's a big compliment to anyone imo), plus it is an implied apology, which is enough to ignite our compassion.

Still, I would like to seek what Chazal meant [when they instituted](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.87a.13) this phraseology, *forgive me*. It's very interesting to note that nobody ever apologises to anyone else in Torah in the way we do (except to Hashem) - neither "forgive me" or "I am sorry" - and [this is a very interesting article](https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/no-apologies-just-a-kiss/) with a theory about why that is*. It would be nice to hear answers sourced in tradition as to why that is and how the minhag developed to ask for forgiveness.

**So basically my question is, why do we place the focus of apologising on "forgive *me*", and not simply "I'm so sorry for what I did"? The latter sounds much more authentic and appropriate to anyone striving to be other-centric, and to be genuinely concerned for the preciousness and wellbeing of his fellow. Are there any sources that discuss this, and particularly any that raise my point here?**

---

<sup>* It states, along with deals with a few cases such as Joseph and the brothers, Avshalom and David, Jacob and Esav etc.:</sup>

> <sup>There are simply no stories anywhere in the Bible – using any terms –
> where one person expresses remorse to another, and that person, in
> turn, accepts the gesture and expresses forgiveness.</sup>

Comment: "what Chazal meant when they instituted this phraseology "selach oti", forgive me. " Where do you see that Chazal instituted such a phraseology?

Comment: @JoelK sorry, you are right, I am having trouble finding the exact origin using that phraseology, although clearly in modern times this is the "minhag" i.e. "asking forgiveness from people", and that's how it seems most people do it. Here seems to be the origin of the phrase, but using a slightly different lashon https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.87a.13

Comment: Btw, note that the reference from Yoma quotes the verse about the brothers apologizing to Yosef

Comment: @שלום yes a very interesting encounter that doesn't involve apologising how we do it today. You'll certainly find people seeking forgiveness in Torah, but you wont find expressions of remorse followed by explicit expressions of forgiveness in the Torah (according to that article, I haven't found any counter examples yet)

Comment: Shaul apologized to Dovid וַיֹּ֙אמֶר֙ אֶל־דָּוִ֔ד צַדִּ֥יק אַתָּ֖ה מִמֶּ֑נִּי כִּ֤י אַתָּה֙ גְּמַלְתַּ֣נִי הַטּוֹבָ֔ה וַאֲנִ֖י גְּמַלְתִּ֥יךָ הָרָעָֽה׃ 
He said to David, “You are right, not I; for you have treated me generously, but I have treated you badly.

Comment: @Chatzkel see my edit.